# Define Parameters Programmatically for GridView Select Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to show a Gridview that lists information in a database based on a query.  The query takes a parameter of a string, how do you define what this parameter is.  An example of the screen I am stuck at is:

http://static.asp.net/asp.net/images/dataaccess/07fig08cs.png

An example of the code I want to use is:

parameter for my object data source select query = OBDS_Query_Parameter

OBDS_Query_Parameter = str;

### Edit

---

Sorry Im not sure how to explain it...

For instance if I have a query that `GetAllProducts(String userName);` How do I pass or define what `userName` is when using the data gridview.  I am using an Object DataSource and linking the data Gridview to that.

I can do this without the object data source and strictly melodramatically like this:

```
quartz_SongsTableAdapter songsAdapter = new quartz_SongsTableAdapter();
CurrentRole = "admin";
GridView1.DataSource = songsAdapter.GetSongForClient(CurrentRole);
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate tags ("ASP.NET C#") in the title. Just leave them in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Not so clear about your question, I hope I'm not misunderstanding.

```
IDataParameter p;
p = DataProvider.GetDataParameter(....)
```